# Distance a block slides along a surface with friction given with an initial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

For this part (e) of this problem,
[image]
Source: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-01sc-...647ea989a352a972dc4b3dfe_MIT8_01F16_pset7.pdf

The solutions are,
[image]
However, I don't understand why they only used a component of the initial velocity as it comes off the incline. I used 4.38 m/s because I thought that once the block reaches the horizontal surface, the velocity would be the same. Dose anybody know conceptually what happened the vertical component of velocity before coming off the inclined plane? Do you please know why or whether the solutions are wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component of the velocity along the x direction is used because at the instant the block leaves the incline and moves into the flat surface, the downward component of the velocity is lost (due to normal contact force or whatever).

At that instant, we know that no force acts along the positive x direction (considering instants when transitioning between 2 different planes is quite tricky, but intuitively you can understand that these are limiting cases and hence the velocity cannot appreciably change due to friction in this instant).

We also know the body doesn't move downwards after the transition (it would be absurd) therefore we assume the particle moves on the flat surface with the component of velocity it had along x when it was moving on the incline plane.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer!